# javac fails with symbol not found

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, javac

Here is my folder structure:

```
- myGame/
  - bin/
  - src/
     - common/
     - logic/
     - main/
     - messageprotocol/
     - test/
     - util/
         - Test.java
         - Rectangle.java
         - Geometry.java
```

I would like to compile Test.java which is in util package. However, I get symbol not found errors, I guess javac command is wrong. Also, you should know that Test.java has references to other classes within the same project (myGame).

Here is what I do:

```
cd myGame/
javac -d bin -classpath bin src/util/Test.java
```

Once I'm done with above, I'd do this and it would work (I hope):

```
cd myGame/bin
java Test
```

I have read a lot of resources and tried to apply but it didn't work for my folder structure. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Errors I receive are:

```
myGame/src/util/Test.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Rectangle
location: class util.Test
  private static final Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[someNumber];
                       ^
myGame/src/util/Test.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Rectangle
location: class util.Test
  private static final Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[someNumber];
                                                          ^
myGame/src/util/Test.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Geometry
location: class util.Test
    System.out.println("Printing " + Geometry.NUMBER);
                                                      ^
myGame/src/util/Test.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Geometry
location: class util.Test
      serverSocket = new Circle(Geometry.NUMBER);
                                      ^
myGame/src/util/Test.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Rectangle
location: class util.Test
            rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(number, rectangles);
                                   ^
5 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package structure for your `Test.java` is `util.Test` so you should do:

```
cd myGame/src
javac -d ../bin -classpath ../bin util/Test.java
```

and then try running it. hope this helps.

Comment: I still get the same errors. Actually this command gives even more errors because you mentioned bin folder in wrong address, it is one level up. But even if I fix that, the errors don't go away.

Comment: i updated the path to bin. did you updated bin folder path in class path as well?

Comment: Yeah I did. Both -d and -classpath.

Comment: I've updated the error messages and folder structure, please check. Thanks!

Comment: It seams you have not imported required packages. Kindly post Test.java as well

Comment: If you look at the folder structure, all the classes that seem not to be imported with these errors are actually in the same package as Test.java, so they don't need to be imported. This is the main problem, why would I get a not found error for classes within the same package?

Comment: it seems you should use `javac -d ../bin -classpath .;../bin util/Test.java`

Comment: This is what I get when I execute above command:

javac: no source files

Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: ../bin: Is a directory

Comment: It should get executed. Try setting classpath first by `set CLASSPATH=.;../bin` and than `javac -d ../bin util/Test.java`

Comment: I cannot set classpath like that. I get the error -bash: ../bin: Is a directory

Comment: On unix replace ; with : and it will work  . I assumed you are using windows .. my bad .. sorry

Comment: It was my Java version (updated to 1.7 from 1.6)! After updating, and replacing ; with :, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I execute this now? For some reason it keeps not finding the class. Do I correctly set the classpath to the bin directory?

Comment: @Squirrelkiller it depends on your project structure, if it matches with the one in question then suggested way shall work for you

Comment: My structure is even simpler, I just have a few classes all in src/utils/ referencing each other. Turns out I don't have to include bin in the path to the class I want to run :D

Comment: bin is the directory where all the compiled classes were put in context of above question.. so if your compiled classes are in some other directory then please include that